# Why does the systemd service running successfully on CentOS 7 is not working on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, systemd, services

I updated one of my servers from CentOS 7 to CentOS 8.

I have a stream server that works with UDP and TCP protocols. I allowed ports. In short, everything is great except **systemctl**.

- service name: mytt.service

Config running on CentOS 7:

```
# mytt server

[Unit]
Description=My TeamTalk5 server
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64
WorkingDirectory=/home/mytt1
ExecStart=/home/mytt1/tt5srv -nd -c /home/mytt1/tt5srv.xml -l /var/log/teamtalk/tt5srv.log
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I connect with ssh and type ExecStart normally, the server runs successfully.
So:

```
cd /home/mytt1
./tt5srv -nd -c /home/mytt1/tt5srv.xml -l /var/log/teamtalk/tt5srv.log
```

Here's `systemctl status mytt` output:

```
systemctl status mytt
● mytt.service - My TeamTalk5 server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mytt.service; disabled; vendor preset: d>
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-01-02 04:42:35 EST; 6s ago
  Process: 1831 ExecStart=/home/mytt1/tt5srv -nd -c /home/mytt1/tt5srv.xml -l />
 Main PID: 1831 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 02 04:42:35 centos systemd[1]: Started My TeamTalk5 server.
Jan 02 04:42:35 centos systemd[1]: mytt.service: Main process exited, code=exit>
Jan 02 04:42:35 centos systemd[1]: mytt.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-9/9 (END)
```

I suspect there is a linking error.
ldd output:

```
[root@centos mytt1]# cd mytt1/
[root@centos mytt1]# ldd tt5srv
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd86bb3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0bbe8ed000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0bbe6e9000)
        libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f0bbe47a000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f0bbe017000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0bbdc82000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0bbd900000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0bbd6e8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0bbd325000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0bbeb0d000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0bbd10e000)
```

I don't know what has changed in CentOS from version 7 to 8.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any error message? Either in the tt5srv.log file or in systemctl status (you can scroll to the right as indicated by the `>` at the right of the screen)?

Answer (score 1):

I see you first do `cd /home/mytt1`.  That's not part of your `ExecStart=`.  You can try adding `WorkingDirectory=/home/mytt1` to get the same behavior.

Next, `User=root`, `Group=root` is implied.  When you this via `ssh`, were you `root`?  Consider changing the User/Group to `mytt1`.

Other than that, the I see the exit code is 203.  That is `systemd`'s way of saying that it can't run the binary.  This often means that the binary is missing, is not executable, or perhaps it's a linker error where it can't find a dependency.  Since this is a CentOS 7 vs 8 thing, I'd bet on the linker error.  What is this application?  Do you have any specific RPATH set that would be fixed with the `WorkingDirectory=`? or perhaps a special `ldconfig` on your CentOS 7 machine?

Assuming it's a library error, you should be able to find out which library is missing from StandardError. However, `StandardOutput=` and `StandardError=` are set to `syslog`. This is [not a supported value](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) in the latest versions of systemd. This could be why you can't see what the linker error is.  Try setting this to `journal` and you may get a better error message telling you which library is not found.

The fact that you can run this from a terminal, but not from systemd suggests the environment is different.  I'm guessing that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set in your `.bashrc` and your program depends on something in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Check with `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  If that's the case, then systemd won't be able to find any libraries in that directory.  You can use [`ldconfig`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) to add some libraries system-wide so that it does work, or you could add `Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` to your service file.

You can also run `ldd /home/mytt1/tt5srv` so see which libraries are linked and see if there is something in a non-standard location. That should give you a hint about what is missing in your environment.

Comment: Yes, it could be a linking problem.
When running the program for the first time it said that libssl.so was missing. I installed libssl. Now it doesn't fail in SSH as root.
I think systemd has set the correct lib paths. If not, how can I specify this?
Program is 64 bit.

Comment: I've added details about troubleshooting linking problems to the answer.  Good luck!

Comment: I updated my systemd config. Can you check again?
Again not working.
How can I view a detailed log? Can you explain?

Comment: Look for selinux avcs too. A daemon running as root and listening on certain ports might have issues running out of a home directory.

Comment: Everything that is logged is now in `journalctl -u mytt`.  It also looks like all libraries that would cause 203 are in `/lib64`, not `/usr/lib64`.  If you type `sudo ldconfig -p` do you see these libraries printed?  If not, change your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/lib64`

Comment: @Stewart  I don't really know `/lib64` location.
Redirects to `/usr/lib64`.
I wrote it this way because I was thinking about it. But now I fixed the problem with **bash**.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok that might be a CentOS thing.  Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't fix this with **pure systemd**.
In my case I had to create a start.sh file.

I placed the file in the main location of the service (/home/mytt1) :).

That's it:

```
# start server shell

/home/mytt1/tt5srv -nd -c /home/mytt1/tt5srv.xml -l /var/log/teamtalk/tt5srv.log
```

In the root account (or service user account):

```
chmod +x start.sh
```

And the service file:

```
# mytt server

[Unit]
Description=My TeamTalk5 server
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64 /usr/lib"
WorkingDirectory=/home/mytt1
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/mytt1/start.sh
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What could do  Bash but **not systemd**? That's interesting.
There were no detailed **logs in the journal**. So I could not get the details.
I hope someone can find a nicer solution.